# Subset Sum theory and solutions

Tags: computation-theory, subset-sum

Subset problem is defined in Wikipedia as follows:

> Given a set of integers, is there a non-empty
>   subset whose sum is zero? For example, given the set { −7, −3, −2, 5,
>   8}, the answer is yes because the subset { −3, −2, 5} sums to zero.

or

> given a set of integers and an integer s, does any non-empty subset sum to s?

Brute force solution for this problem is exponential (cycle through all subsets of N numbers and, for every one of them, check if the subset sums to the right number), there some optimized version for brute force running in exponential time as well.

Let suppose there is an algorithm that can compute a brute force solution (exact solution to above questions) in between quadratic and polynomial time complexity

How it would be considered related to P=NP question, time complexity and so on?

Supposing algorithm exists, would be an improvement to state of the art for the subset sum problem?

(I'm not an expert on this area so if something does not make sense or is not clear I'll provide additional input to this question to the extent I'm able to :) )

Comment: This is a mathematics question.

Answer (score 2):

Since the subset problem is NP-complete, if you can find a polynomial time solution to the problem, then you can solve all problems in NP in polynomial time, and P = NP.

Now, of course the above statement wouldn't make sense without understanding what NP and NP-completeness are. There are many ways to define NP problems, but the simplest way is that a problem is in NP if and only if there exists a verifier that can check the correctness of its solution in polynomial time. In the case of the subset sum problem, clearly you can verify its solution in polynomial time. Therefore, it's an NP problem.

The class NP-complete is a special set of problems in NP such that all problems in NP can be reduced to any problem in NP-complete in polynomial time. As an example, the first proven NP-complete problem by Cook is the SAT problem, where you try to decide if there exists a possible assignment to a set of boolean variables such that a boolean formula would evaluate to true. With the correct procedure, you can transform all decision problems in NP to SAT in polynomial time, and this makes SAT NP-complete. You can find more details about the original proof [here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=800157.805047), but it requires some understanding of the Turing machine.

To prove the NP-completeness of a new problem, you can try to reduce an existing NP-complete problem to the new one. As an example, we know that the SAT problem can be easily reduced to a 3-SAT problem. This means given a SAT problem, we can transform it into a 3-SAT version such that solving the equivalent 3-SAT problem would give us the result of the original SAT problem. Since all problems in NP can be reduced to SAT, and SAT can be reduced to 3-SAT, this makes the 3-SAT problem NP-complete.

[Here](http://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DD1352/adk12/alvie/subsetSumNPCompleteness.pdf) is a nice proof of how you can reduce 3-SAT to the subset sum problem. As a consequence of the proof, the subset sum problem is NP-complete. Hence, if you can find a polynomial time solution to the subset sum problem, you can then solve all NP problems (yes, including problems such as the traveling salesman, graph coloring, knapsack, etc.) in polynomial time (since all reductions are done in polynomial time).